# Why SSRS report fonts are rendered different on IIS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using Gotham and PT sans fonts for SSRS Report which are reflecting in the SSRS Report on Localhost but when I am trying to see same in IIS, fonts are not Reflecting.
I have already added fonts in C drive fonts folder.

Why SSRS report fonts are rendered different on IIS?
Is there any way to solve this Issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the fonts are installed on your Report Server as well since that is where SSRS will be expecting to find them.

Comment: It is working now. I just deployed the reports and restart the IIS and checked it again, and now fonts are coming as expected.

Comment: That is what I would've suggested next! Glad you got it sorted